# Chrome extension: store data on background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I want to be able to store data on background (on my extension) so I can access this data between multiple domains.

Where's what I'm doing:

**content-script.js**

```
function setItem(name, data) {
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({ command: 'setItem', name: name, data: data });
}

function getItem(name) {
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({ command: 'getItem', name: name }, function(response) {
        return response;
    });
}
```

**background-script.js**

```
Storage.prototype.setObject = function(key, value) {
    this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}

Storage.prototype.getObject = function(key) {
    var value = this.getItem(key);
    return value && JSON.parse(value);
}

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch (request.command) {
        case 'setItem':
            localStorage.setObject(request.name, request.data);
            return;
        case 'getItem':
            sendResponse(localStorage.getObject(request.name));
            return;
    }
});
```

But without sucess, since I cant return from inside the callback on **getItem**.

I do get the data inside the `function(response) { }` callback, I just can't return it as the return of **getItem**.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 20):

This 2012 question was brought up for an up-to-date answer. Well, then..

Right now the proper answer would be to use [`chrome.storage` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage). It's an API accessible for both extension pages and content scripts, and it provides asynchronous storage. It requires `"storage"` permission, but this permission generates no warnings.

```
// Setting
chrome.storage.local.set({key: data}, function() {
  if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    console.error(
      "Error setting " + key + " to " + JSON.stringify(data) +
      ": " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message
    );
  }
});

// Getting
chrome.storage.local.get("key", function(data) {
  // Do something with data.key
});
```

See also the [Examples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#examples) part of the documentation.

Note that in either case (this approach, or messaging-the-background approach) you can't make a function `getData` that *returns* a result, since the call is asynchronous.

Some tips and tricks:

1. You can set or get multiple values at once by passing an object or an array as a query. You can read all values by passing the `null` query.
2. You can provide a default value for the `get()` operation in case there's no value stored for the key, by passing a query like `{key: defaultValue}`
3. You can be notified of all changes to the storage with `chrome.storage.onChanged` event.
4. `chrome.storage.local` obeys `"unlimitedStorage"` permission.
5. `chrome.storage.sync` will propagate the value to all profiles signed in to the same Google Account, if Chrome Sync is enabled for extensions. However, keep [quotas](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-sync) in mind.
6. If you absolutely need synchronous access, you can fake it with a local cache backed by `chrome.storage`. There are, however, limitations: while in a synchronous code block, your cache won't be updated with changes from other pages, and you need to read the values once asynchronously to populate the cache.

Comment: also make sure that you don't use reserved keywords like 'history' when saving your objects... lost too much time with this one.

Comment: Good answer,many of us missed this api while reading documentation.|
btw can you tell where can we see this stored data?from the developer tool..

Answer (score 5):

Content.js

```
var someVar = "hey hey!";

chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "fromContentScript",greeting: someVar}, function(response) {

    console.log(response.data); // response back from BG

    if(response.who == 'bg'){ // checks if the response is from BG
            //Something happened ...
    }

    var responseFromBg = response.data; // the response incase we need to use the message sent back... in this case should be 'hey yourself'


});
```

Background.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  // From content script.
  if (sender.tab) {
    if (request.method == "fromContentScript"){

        localStorage.setItem("welcome-message",request.greeting); // in this case there will now be a localStorage variable called 'welcome-message' set with the value of 'hey hey!'. This will be viewable in the chrome:extensions page, click on the 'background.html / generated background.html' then view the 'Development Tools' or in Windows hit 'CTRL + SHIFT + I' and look at the 'LocalStorage' tab...

      sendResponse({who: "bg",data: "hey yourself"}); // this is the response sent back, 'who' tells the content page where is responding, so it can do something with the response if needed.
        }else{
      sendResponse({}); // snub them.
        }
  }
});
```

Manifest.json // just incase it is a manifest issue you are having... here is most of mine..

```
{
  "name": "Name here",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Enter desc here.",  
    "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon16.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },    
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "*://*/*"
  ],
    "icons": { "16": "img/icon16.png",
           "48": "img/icon48.png",
          "128": "img/icon128.png" },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js","content_script.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
}
```

Would have used your example, but I am in a hurry this morn. I have tried to explain all of the vars as carefully as possible - sorry :(

Comment: sendRequest ans onRequest are deprecated

Comment: @Chris I tried your example but unfortunately  doesn't work, could you please help me out :)

Comment: 1st i don't know where to see my `database` created, 2nd i used your `background js` and `content js` but with no help

Comment: You need to open the background page using the Extensions page, then F12 and view the Local Storage under 'Resources' tab

Answer (score 1):

**background-script.js:**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch (request.command) {
        case 'setItem':
            localStorage[request.name] = JSON.stringify(request.data));
            return;
        case 'getItem':
            var retValue;
            if (typeof(localStorage[request.name]) === 'string') {
                retValue = JSON.parse(localStorage[request.name]);
            }
            sendResponse(retValue);
            return;
        case 'deleteItem':
            if (typeof localStorage[request.name] !== 'undefined') {
                delete localStorage[request.name];
            }
            return;
    }
});
```

If the key is not in the localStorage, getItem will return `undefined`. Instead of defining the function `getItem` the way you did, you should send a message to the background with a callback and then do something with the value when the callback is called. You can't return the value from the function `getItem`, but you can use the value in the callback when it is called:

```
function getItem(name, callback) {
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({command: 'getItem', name: name}, function(response) {
        if (typeof(callback) === "function") {
            callback(response);
        }
    });
}
```